# Response Message in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem with throw error message. Event `statusCode == 0` but it still chose `this.snackBar.open(`Cannot Proses!`+ err, "OK", snackBarConfig);`. How to make it chose `this.snackBar.open(`Success!`, "OK", snackBarConfig);`

**Component Service**

```
return this.http.post(url, userData, httpOptions).pipe(
      map((response)=>{
        if(response['statusCode'] !== 0){
          throw new Error(response['statusMessage']);
        }else{
          throw new Error(response['statusMessage']);
        }
      })
    )
```

**Component**

```
this.userservice.userForm(test).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
          this.snackBar.open(`Success!`, "OK", snackBarConfig);
        },
        err => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
          this.snackBar.open(`Cannot Proses!` + err, "OK", snackBarConfig);
            console.log("check error:" + err);

        }
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the else branch of the condition.

```
return this.http.post(url, userData, httpOptions).pipe(
      map((response)=>{
        if(response['statusCode'] !== 0){
          throw new Error(response['statusMessage']);
        }
      })
    )
```